# Got NullPointerException from Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I'm writing a little Android game. It should display a random sequence of 4 animals which i implemented as ImageButtons. The user has to remember this sequence and repeat it afterwards.

My problem now is the right timing how the Imagebuttons get visible.

I got the following NullPointerException and couldn't figure out why. Maybe anyone can help!?

Heres my Main Activity:

```
package lichtenberger.paul;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Game extends Activity {

    int Reihenfolge[] = new int[40];

    Random generator = new Random();


    public final int CAT = 0;
    public final int MAN = 1;
    public final int BIRD = 2;
    public final int SHEEP = 3;
    public Handler handler;
    public Thread AnimalThread;
    {for(int i = 0; i<40; i++)Reihenfolge[i]=generator.nextInt(4);}


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        final ImageButton cat = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.catButton);
        final ImageButton sheep = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sheepButton);
        final ImageButton man = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.manButton);
        final ImageButton bird = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.birdButton);
        final TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreNTV);

        handler = new Handler(){

            @Override

            public void handleMessage(Message msg){

                switch (msg.what) {
                case 0:
                    cat.setVisibility(1);
                    man.setVisibility(0);
                    bird.setVisibility(0);
                    sheep.setVisibility(0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    man.setVisibility(1);
                    bird.setVisibility(0);
                    sheep.setVisibility(0);
                    cat.setVisibility(0);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    bird.setVisibility(1);
                    sheep.setVisibility(0);
                    cat.setVisibility(0);
                    man.setVisibility(0);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sheep.setVisibility(1);
                    cat.setVisibility(0);
                    man.setVisibility(0);
                    bird.setVisibility(0);
                    break;
                }

            }
        };          
            ShowSequence show = new ShowSequence();
            Thread showSeq = new Thread(show);
            showSeq.start();

        };

}
```

My Thread Class:

```
package lichtenberger.paul;   

public class ShowSequence extends Game implements Runnable{    
    @Override
    public void run() {                 
        show();
    }

    private void show() {

        for(int i = 0; i<40; i++){
        switch (Reihenfolge[i]) {
        case 0:
                try {
                // this pauses the Thread: Alternative to doing stuff...
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                handler.sendEmptyMessage(CAT);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();}
                break;

        case 1:
            try {
                // this pauses the Thread: Alternative to doing stuff...
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                handler.sendEmptyMessage(MAN);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            try {
                // this pauses the Thread: Alternative to doing stuff...
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                handler.sendEmptyMessage(BIRD);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 3: 
            try {
                // this pauses the Thread: Alternative to doing stuff...
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                handler.sendEmptyMessage(SHEEP);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}}
```

and my LogCat:

```
12-20 15:20:34.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-75
12-20 15:20:34.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 15:20:34.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598):     at lichtenberger.paul.ShowSequence.show(ShowSequence.java:50)
12-20 15:20:34.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598):     at lichtenberger.paul.ShowSequence.run(ShowSequence.java:10)
12-20 15:20:34.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

EDIT:

the whole code in one Activity which didnt work:

```
package lichtenberger.paul;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Game extends Activity {

    int Reihenfolge[] = new int[40];

    Random generator = new Random();
    public ImageButton cat;
    public ImageButton man;
    public ImageButton bird;
    public ImageButton sheep;
    public TextView score;
    private static Handler handler;
    public final int CAT = 0;
    public final int MAN = 1;
    public final int BIRD = 2;
    public final int SHEEP = 3;
    public Runnable showAnimal;
    public Thread AnimalThread;
    {for(int i = 0; i<40; i++)Reihenfolge[i]=generator.nextInt(4);}


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        setupUI();
        showSequence();
        initHandler();
    }



    public void showSequence() {

                showAnimal = new showAnimal();
                AnimalThread = new Thread(showAnimal);
                AnimalThread.start();


    }



    public void setupUI() {

        cat = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.catButton);
        sheep = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sheepButton);
        man = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.manButton);
        bird = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.birdButton);
        score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreNTV);

    }

    private void initHandler() {
        handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case CAT:
                    cat.setVisibility(1);
                    man.setVisibility(0);
                    bird.setVisibility(0);
                    sheep.setVisibility(0);
                    break;
                case MAN:
                    man.setVisibility(1);
                    bird.setVisibility(0);
                    sheep.setVisibility(0);
                    cat.setVisibility(0);
                    break;
                case BIRD:
                    bird.setVisibility(1);
                    sheep.setVisibility(0);
                    cat.setVisibility(0);
                    man.setVisibility(0);
                    break;
                case SHEEP:
                    sheep.setVisibility(1);
                    cat.setVisibility(0);
                    man.setVisibility(0);
                    bird.setVisibility(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

    }

    class showAnimal implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            show();
        }

        private void show() {

            for(int i = 0;i<40;i++){

            switch (Reihenfolge[i]) {

            case 0:
                try {
                    // this pauses the Thread: Alternative to doing stuff...
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(CAT);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                try {
                    // this pauses the Thread: Alternative to doing stuff...
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(MAN);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                try {
                    // this pauses the Thread: Alternative to doing stuff...
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(SHEEP);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                try {
                    // this pauses the Thread: Alternative to doing stuff...
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(BIRD);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }



}
}
```

Thanks for help ;)

Comment: what is on line 50 of ShowSequence class?

Comment: the error is always on the lines that send messages to handler. In this case it's: handler.sendEmptyMessage(BIRD);

Comment: Your class hierarchy is somewhat odd. In ``Game.onCreate`` you instantiate ``new ShowSequence`` which extends ``Game`` and though creates new ``Activity`` (it never gets its ``onCreate`` called btw). Maybe you should write your ``Runnable`` as private class inside ``Game`` instead?

Comment: right, what you get if you print the msg variable inside this method "public void handleMessage(Message msg) {...}" ?

Comment: I already tried to put everything in the Game activity but it didnt work out for me. It showed all 4 pictures at once instead of pausing the thread for 2 seconds and then show the new picture. I add the code of the whole class as i tried before. Maybe anyone has got an idea to solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 separate objects - instance of `Game` that has non-null handler. And instance of `ShowSequence` with null handler. You shouldn't inherit `ShowSequecne` from `Game`. It doesn't get all `Game`'s variables automically, you should make `ShowSequence` inner class of in `Game` as @harism suggested.
Or you have to set all variables in `ShowSequence` explicitly in constructor or immediately after you created it.

Comment: I already tried to put it as inner class in game. But the it shows all 4 images at once instead of in a sequence with 2 seconds delay in between :/

Comment: @PaulLich you can avoid threads at all. Use [sendEmptyMessageDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendEmptyMessageDelayed%28int,%20long%29) inside handler's `handleMessage` method send empty message to itself with 2000 delay.

Comment: Alright, thanks. sendEmptyMessageDelayed worked. But the actual Problem was a different one which I discovered while debugging. The reason why all of the pictures appeared at once was starting threads in like really short time between. I solved this by changing delaytime after every loop of my showSequence method. I post my solution below my question.

Answer (score 0):

Paul,

Have you tried making the "handler" variable **volatile**? You access this variable from your worker thread (that is running your "ShowSequence" runnable) without using synchronization (the **synchronized** keyword). Although you may even want to consider adding some form of synchronization (I didn't go through your code enough to make that determination) you should at least make sure that writes to 'handler' from one thread are visible to other threads. The volatile qualifier is a way to accomplish that.

Good luck!

PS: ShowSequence extends Game? Which in turn extends Activity? I think you need to check this inheritance tree as well.. Not sure if you would want this..

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't innert the ShowSequence from a Game, you could pass the handler as a parameter

//Activity

```
ShowSequence show = new ShowSequence(handler);
            Thread showSeq = new Thread(show);
            showSeq.start();
```

// Thread class

```
public class ShowSequence implements Runnable{
Handler handler = null;

public ShowSequence(handler){
      this.handler = handler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual Problem was a different one which I discovered while debugging. The reason why all of the pictures appeared at once was starting threads in like really short time between. I solved this by changing delaytime after every loop of my showSequence method.

So here's my full class now:

```
package lichtenberger.paul;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Game extends Activity {

    int Reihenfolge[] = new int[40];

    Random generator = new Random();


    public final int CAT = 0;
    public final int MAN = 1;
    public final int BIRD = 2;
    public final int SHEEP = 3;
    public final int PAUSE = 4;
    public final int ALL = 5;
    public int Zug = 40;
    public int time = 0;
    public Handler handler;
    public Thread AnimalThread;
    public ImageButton cat;
    public ImageButton man;
    public ImageButton bird;
    public ImageButton sheep;

    {for(int i = 0; i<40; i++)Reihenfolge[i]=generator.nextInt(4);}


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        cat = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.catButton);
        sheep = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sheepButton);
        man = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.manButton);
        bird = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.birdButton);
        final TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreNTV);

        handler = new Handler(){

            @Override

            public void handleMessage(Message msg){

                switch (msg.what) {
                case CAT:
                    cat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    man.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    bird.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    sheep.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    break;
                case MAN:
                    man.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bird.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    sheep.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    cat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    break;
                case BIRD:
                    bird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sheep.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    cat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    man.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    break;
                case SHEEP:
                    sheep.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    man.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    bird.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    break;

                case PAUSE:
                    sheep.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    cat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    man.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    bird.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                case ALL:
                    sheep.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    man.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 }

            }
        };

        time = 0;
        Zug = 40;
        showGameSeq(time, Zug); 
        }



    public int showGameSeq(int time, int Zug) {
        ShowSequence show;
        Thread showSeq;
        int x = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i<=Zug; ++i, ++x){

                if(Reihenfolge[i-1]!=Reihenfolge[i-1]){

                    show = new ShowSequence(Reihenfolge[i-1], time);
                    showSeq = new Thread(show);
                    showSeq.start();
                    time = time + 1000;}

                else{
                    show = new ShowSequence(Reihenfolge[i-1], time);
                    showSeq = new Thread(show);
                    showSeq.start();
                    time = time + 1000;

                    show = new ShowSequence(PAUSE, time);
                    showSeq = new Thread(show);
                    showSeq.start();
                    time = time + 500;

                }
            }


        if(x==Zug){ 
        show = new ShowSequence(ALL, time);
        showSeq = new Thread(show);
        showSeq.start();
        }else{};


        return time;
    };



    private class ShowSequence implements Runnable{

        int which;
        int time;

        public ShowSequence(int which, int time) {
            this.which = which;
            this.time = time;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            show();

        }

        private void show() {

                switch (which) {
                case CAT:

                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CAT, time);
                    break;
                case MAN:

                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MAN, time);
                    break;
                case BIRD:

                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(BIRD, time);
                    break;
                case SHEEP:

                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SHEEP, time);
                    break;

                case PAUSE:

                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(PAUSE, time);
                    break;

                case ALL:

                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(ALL, time);
                    break;

                }
        }
        }
        }
```

Thanks to everyone inspiring my solution!!! :)